# Show that complex Integral of 1/z on an ellipse is equal to the integral on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that if I have two curves:

[image]

Where $a,b > 0$ and $a \neq b$. Then,

[image]

There is also a hint that suggests splitting curves into two parts such as lower and upper half-planes and using the Cauchy Integral Theorem to calculate both integrals. However, I could not calculate it. How can I show that both integrals are equal?

Edit: On the textbook "Complex Analysis 2nd ed. Freitag, Busam" there is a solution, but the explanation is not clear to me:

One can split the curve α, and correspondingly β, into the pieces in the upper and lower half-plane, α = α+ ⊕ α−, α+ = α|[0, 1/2], α− = α|[1/2, 1]. The Cauchy Integral Theorem can be used to show that the integrals along the two pieces are correspondingly equal. For this, slit the plane along the positive, and respectively the negative imaginary axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $0<a<b.$ Let $\alpha_1$ be the top of $\alpha,$ and $\beta_1$ be the top of $\beta.$ Then by Cauchy

$$\int_{\alpha_1}\frac{1}{z}\,dz - \int_{\beta_1}\frac{1}{z}\,dz =0.$$

Similarly, let $\alpha_2$ be the bottom of $\alpha,$ and $\beta_2$ be the bottom of $\beta.$ Then

$$\int_{\alpha_2}\frac{1}{z}\,dz - \int_{\beta_2}\frac{1}{z}\,dz =0.$$

Therefore

$$\int_{\alpha_1}\frac{1}{z}\,dz+\int_{\alpha_2}\frac{1}{z}\,dz = \int_{\beta_1}\frac{1}{z}\,dz +\int_{\beta_2}\frac{1}{z}\,dz.$$

The left side of this is $\int_{\alpha}\dfrac{1}{z}\,dz.$ The right side is $\int_{\beta}\dfrac{1}{z}\,dz.$

Comment: With this logic, then the integral over the circle will be $0$ as well, which is not the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: I rewrote my answer. Hope it helps.